# How can I use column alias in later part of a hive query

Tags: hadoop, hive, column-alias

Is there a way to use column alias declared earlier later in the query? I have something like this

```
select item_id, 
       sum(sales) as total_sales,
       sum(cost) as total_cost
       total_sales - total_cost as total_profit
       from table A
       group by item_id,total_profit;
```

I tried using

```
SET hive.groupby.orderby.position.alias=true;
```

but doesn't work.

I know I can do this in Teradata so I am hoping there must be some way to do this in Hive as well.

thanks,

Manoj Agrawal

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot create `total_profit` using a derived table?

Comment: Yeah, I have like 5 derived tables already and over 100 columns in select with 37 million rows to select. Trying to reduce the number of tables and sub-queries to optimize the processing time.